# Insert/Play Local Video Path File With HTML5 Video Tag

Tags: html, file, video, path, mp4

I'm trying to play a MP4 video using video tag, but nothing is displayed. When I have my video in the same project directory the video plays, but I need to have the video in another directory. This is my code:

```
      <div id= "show">
          <video width="320" height="240" src="file:///F:/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" controls>
          </video>
      </div>
```

The problem is the path, so, what is the correct way to declare file's path?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the mp4 when it's in the other directory and right click on the properties. copy the file path and then paste it in (and precede it by file://). make sure you turn the slashes to turn forward in the file path.

it should look something like this

```
file:///F:/Users/yourname/folder/subfolder/test.mp4
```

Comment: Doesn't work... F:\ does not have Users folder, it's a partition

Comment: That's only an example. Did you look at the properties?

Comment: Yes, This is the path F:\